# modx - when I'm using "&documents=" parameter in ditto snippet, pagination doesn't work

Tags: parameters, modx, ditto

I'm trying run ditto with parameter which holds specific docIDs:

```
&documents=
```

when I put static IDs code to the chunk:

```
[[Ditto? &documents=`9,239,240,242,243,246,253,257,260,261,267,269,281,285,288` &showInMenuOnly=`1` &tpl=`item_subdocs`  &summarize=`2` &paginate=`1` &paginateAlwaysShowLinks=`1`  ]]
[+previous+][+pages+][+next+]
```

it works - pagination, link under the list - it's OK
but when I'm trying to retrieve that IDs dynamically - by some snippet:

```
[[Ditto? &documents=`[[getIDs]]` &showInMenuOnly=`1` &tpl=`item_subdocs`  &summarize=`2` &paginate=`1` &paginateAlwaysShowLinks=`1`  ]]
[+previous+][+pages+][+next+]
```

It doesn't work. The pagination link will disappear, but when I run pages from URL by adding phrase:

```
?start=2
```

It's work... anyone knows what has happened?
Also running simple code from that snippet:

```
echo '9,239,240,242,243,246,253,257,260,261,267,269,281,285,288';
```

.. doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

try to get your snippet to output the values rather than just echoing them:

$output = '9,239,240,242,243,246,253,257,260,261,267,269,281,285,288';

return $output;

Sounds silly but modx can do weird things if snippet calls don't return something.

Comment: I was trying to do it like that, but sorry - nope.. It still doesn't work. Although, thanks for that reply!

Comment: What happens if you try to put your ids in a chunk rather than a snippet?

Comment: Yes. When Im passing that list of IDs in the chunk statically - paginate working, but when Im trying in the snippet - not. Strange, but echoing the same code like in chunk - in the snippet - doesn't working too.

Comment: I described this problem here and found the solution http://forums.modx.com/thread/76718/ditto-documents-pagination---strange-problem